# ClassNotFoundExceptions when accessing database

Tags: java, mysql, classpath

Whenever I put

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Movies";
```

it gives me a "ClassNotFoundException" and I have tried changing my classpath to .; but it doesn't work I think it is a problem with my classpath which I changed in the enviroment variables can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you post the exact stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have mysql java [connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in the classpath of your application.

Comment: Thank you, I was changing the CLASSPATH in the wrong place what had to do was exactly as you said and change the CLASSPATH in my IDE THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Put the connection part in a try catch block if you want to try and trap the Exception and get some details. Also you need com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class, so reference it properly from your class.

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Movies?user=<username>&password=<password>") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all, it cannot find the class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

First you need to download the jar file from MySql.  It comes zipped up, so you must explode it.

Second, you need to point to the jar file in your build path.  You did not specify what you are using to build.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to look after: the environment variable is CLASSPATH (all uppercase).

The rule of thumb is (I'm assuming you're on Windows):

- When adding compiled classes which have not been packaged in a Jar file, the CLASSPATH must contain the path which is considered the root of the
- When adding JAR files to the CLASSPATH, add them as regular files.

Setting the `CLASSPATH` variable to `C:\EX1\BAZ;C:\EX2\lib.jar` means that a class `com.foo.MyClass` has to be located on `C:\EX1\BAZ\com\foo\MyClass.class` or packaged inside `lib.jar`

Answer (score 0):

1> First of all , Download the Mysql Java Connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/.

2> Extract to a desired folder.

3> Right Click the Project File in your IDE.

4> Go to Build -> Packages -> Add Jar  //This is Netbeans Specific Match the same in your IDE

5> Locate the jar file.

6> Rebuild the project and Deploy.